# Carregar um function depois do retorno success e a pagina redirecionada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte `button`:

```
 <a asp-controller="Checkout" asp-action="Checkout" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block pull-right" onclick="Checkout()">Finalizar</a>
```

ele chama a seguinte `function`:

```
function Checkout() {
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Projeto\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
var arrayProdutos = $.parseJSON(cookieValue);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Checkout/Checkout',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {
        'produtos': arrayProdutos
    },
    success: function (data) {
        produtos.forEach(function (produto, i) {
            produto["Imagem"] = data[i].imagem.replace("~", "");
            produto["Descricao"] = data[i].descricao;

            setCookie();

        });
        CheckoutView();
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('Nao enviou');
    }
});
}
```

Como visto ele vai para o `controller`, depois retorna, no final do `success`, eu chamo outra function:

```
function CheckoutView() {   
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Projeto\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

if (cookieValue != "") {
    produtos = $.parseJSON(cookieValue);
}

total = 0;
$(produtos).each(function (i) {
    total += produtos[i].Valor * produtos[i].Quantidade;
});

    ItemProduto = "";
    $(produtos).each(function (i) {
        ItemProduto += '<tr>';
        ItemProduto += '<td data-th="Product">';
        ItemProduto += '<div class="row">';
        ItemProduto += '<div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src="' + produtos[i].Imagem + '" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>';
        ItemProduto += '<div class="col-sm-10">';
        ItemProduto += '<h4 class="nomargin">' + produtos[i].Nome + '</h4>';
        ItemProduto += '<p>' + produtos[i].Descricao + '</p>';
        ItemProduto += '</div>';
        ItemProduto += '</div>';
        ItemProduto += '</td>';
        ItemProduto += '<td data-th="Price">R$ ' + produtos[i].Valor + '</td>';
        ItemProduto += '<td data-th="Quantity">';
        ItemProduto += '<input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="' + produtos[i].Quantidade + '" id="' + produtos[i].Id + '" onchange="AlterarQtd(' + produtos[i].Id + ',this.value);">';
        ItemProduto += '</td>';
        ItemProduto += '<td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">' + (produtos[i].Valor * produtos[i].Quantidade).toFixed(2) + '</td>';
        ItemProduto += '<td class="actions pull-right" data-th="">';
        ItemProduto += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="RemoveAll(' + produtos[i].Id + ')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>';
        ItemProduto += '</td>';
        ItemProduto += '</tr>';
    });

    $("#produto").html(ItemProduto);
    $("#total").html("R$ " + total.toFixed(2));

}
```

Porém quero que function CheckoutView(), carregue somente depois que minha página foi carregada/redirecionada para outra.

antes eu estava usando: `if (window.location.pathname === "/Checkout/Checkout") {` ou invés `function CheckoutView()` , e dava certo, pois preciso chamar ela de function devido precisar usar depois, para ser chamada em outro momento.

Comment: Em que momento a página é carregada/redirecionada?

Comment: Ela atualmente esta no button: asp-controller="Checkout" asp-action="Checkout", ele vai no get do controller e recarrega, isso ao mesmo tempo que ele faz onclick="Checkout()", na qual vai no metodo POST,

Já tentei deixar o button sem esses atributos, e fazer redirecionamento dentro do success :
success: function (data) {  window.location = "/Checkout/Checkout"; e em seguida  chamar a function, porem ele executa tudo pra depois redirecionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Substitua esse código pelo seu.

```
function Checkout() {
    var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)Projeto\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    var arrayProdutos = $.parseJSON(cookieValue);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Checkout/Checkout',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {
            'produtos': arrayProdutos
        },
        success: function (data) {
             produtos.forEach(function (produto, i) {
                produto["Imagem"] = data[i].imagem.replace("~", "");
                produto["Descricao"] = data[i].descricao;

                setCookie();

            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Nao enviou');
        }
    });
```

> adicione esse ao documento

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
           if (window.location.pathname === "/Checkout/Checkout") {
               CheckoutView();
           }
       })
```